# Sharepoint 2016 - authorisation access with AD Group differents domains

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, trust

i am new in this forum. I am verry happy. Please i new your help.

Here is the Context.

we have a website created on SharePoint 2016 and we use different domain AD groups (Dom1 and Dom2) to give access.

However we have a problem with AD groups.

The SharePoint site is hosted on the Dom1 domain. But we want to give access to people in the Dom2 domain. For this we want to use AD groups. But when we put a person from the Dom1 into a group with the people from the Dom2, the people from the Dom2 do not have access to the SharePoint site. We are obliged to give them direct access from the SharePoint site.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you configure the domain trust between Dom1 and Dom2?

If there is a two-way trust in place, and the SharePoint servers have the necessary port access to the remote domain's Domain Controller, then it is automatic.

If it is a one-way trust, then you need to follow these directions:

https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/01/powershell-for-people-picker-properties/

If there is no domain trust in place, then you either need to create one, or look at alternative technologies, such as ADFS.

Simialr issue for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/128919/sharepoint-one-way-trust-issue.html